# wso2 integration spring boot application

Tags: spring-mvc, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm developing a web application using Spring boot, My requirement includes WSO2 integration.

As I am very new to WSO2 identity server I have couple of doubts.

```
 1. Is wso2 works like syncope?, holds the user information and
    authenticates user using API call and returns JWT token?
 2. Should I keep all the user information separate in a DB and allow WSO2 to
    authenticate?
```

Please adivse me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. WSO2IS can be used as a identity provider. In that case, yes it will be responsible to authenticate the user ( there are many ways to do that, you choose the one which suits to your requirement). It can work with any SSO protocol like SAML, OpenID Connect and many more.

   2. Yes, that is the most common approach I think. Usually every organization has its own store of user information. It may be a LDAP, or RDBMS etc. You can setup WSO2IS to receive the authentication request and let WSO2IS authenticate the user from this existing store.